# Highlighting Text in Search Results

Tags: php, search, search-engines

I was wondering if there was some way to highlight text in bold when you're searching for words. [For example](https://sites.google.com/site/indywrestlingentrancemusiclist/system/app/pages/search?scope=search-site&q=fuego). Currently, [my new website](http://www.antdogs.com/thewemdb/?s=fuego) shows the extract but the first few words as well as Table of Content from Elementor (which I don't know how to remove it).

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnQVJU2BS_0) but my theme (Bard) does not have neither search.php nor content.php, so I have no idea where the code is located. I even don't know if I should create it from scratch to make it work.

I'm not too knowledgeable in PHP, so I don't know where to start.

Best regards.

Comment: PHP is server side, so probably not the best solution.  The solution is probably best run as via client side scripting, like JS/jQuery. Something like this should get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript

Comment: I appreciate the help. However, I already got it solved thanks to a plugin. Appreciate the help nonetheless.

Comment: Fantastic.  Glad you got it solved.  :-)